# Can we update +New button on a SharePoint List to new url

Tags: list, forms, sharepoint-online

I have microsoft form to submit requests which comes and save in a SharePoint List. Users will also have access to the list. Can we make the +New button in the list to redirect to microsoft form.

Can anyone please advise

Comment: The short answer is yes. AFAIK, that requires you to customize the command set for the list in order to run custom logic.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate

Comment: I'm saying it's possible to implement customizers; so, yes, you can. But the only way I'm aware of is to deploy and run custom code that will hide and replace the Out Of Box commands like on the `+New` button. That's not to say there's not a better/easier way; I just don't know it...I'm no sharepoint guy. I'd recommend posting this on the sharepoint exchange to get better help from better folks.